# Binary Search an Array

Tags: arrays

I have this code

```
    Dim intSelection As Integer
    Dim intIndexLocation As Integer


    intSelection = cboGenres.SelectedIndex
    intIndexLocation = Array.BinarySearch(strGenre, intSelection)

    If intIndexLocation >= 0 Then
        lstPlayList.Items.Add(strSongs(intIndexLocation))

    End If
```

strGenre is my array but I get an error saying "Failed to compare two elements in the array." I don't understand why this isn't working

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: This appears to be Visual Basic

Answer (score 0):

What type is strGenre?  This error occurs if the type you are searching doesn't implement a comparison operator.

When the BinarySearch command tries to compare elements of strGenre, it fails.  You can:

1. Use a built-in type instead (like String, assuming strGenre is an array of string-like types);
2. Use a custom type and implement your own comparison operator for the type by implementing IComparable.

[This link might help.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/kb/321292)